# XSLT: How to get a value from a certain element within a variable?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I made a variable in XSLT and I am trying to read a value from an element within the variable. I get the following error message in Visual Studio when trying to debug:

> "To use a result tree fragment in a path expression, first convert it
>   to a node-set using the mxsxl:node-set() function".

As I understand, `mssxl` is not a "real" xslt function, and it may not work on some systems; so I don't want to use it.

How do I get a value from a certain element that's in a variable in XSLT?

Here is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >     

  <xsl:variable name ="TestVariable">
        <video id ="0">foo1</video>
        <video id ="2">foo2</video>
        <video id ="3">foo3</video>
        <video id ="4">foo4</video>
        <video id ="5">foo5</video>
        <video id ="6">foo6</video>
    </xsl:variable>

   <xsl:template match="/">
    <outofloop>
      <a2>
       <xsl:value-of select="$TestVariable/video[@id='6']" />
      </a2>
    </outofloop>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You XSLT is invalid: `<video1>` does not match the `</video>` tag (as well as others). The `<xsl:stylesheet>` is not closed

Comment: Have you looked at these? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907302/storing-html-tags-within-an-xsl-varable
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13200567/can-we-insert-html-tags-in-xsl-variable

Answer (score 3):

The XSLT you have would work in XSLT 2.0.

The issue is that in XSLT 1.0, your **TestVariable** variable holds what is known as a "Result Tree Fragment", and so XSLT cannot access this as it really requires a node-set. You can convert it to a node-set by means of an extension function. Indeed, the function is helpfully named [node-set](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/07/16/nodeset.html).

So, you could do this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
 xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="ms">

  <xsl:variable name ="TestVariable">
        <video id ="0">foo1</video>
        <video id ="2">foo2</video>
        <video id ="3">foo3</video>
        <video id ="4">foo4</video>
        <video id ="5">foo5</video>
        <video id ="6">foo6</video>
    </xsl:variable>

   <xsl:template match="/">
    <outofloop>
      <a2>
       <xsl:value-of select="ms:node-set($TestVariable)/video[@id='6']" />
      </a2>
    </outofloop>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But as you point out, this would restrict its portability.

There is another way though, and that is to use the **document** function to allow the XSLT to reference itself as an input document. Simply define a variable like so

```
<xsl:variable name="Test" select="document('')//xsl:variable[@name='TestVariable']" />
```

Then you can do this

```
<xsl:value-of select="$Test/video[@id='6']" />
```

Because **Test** refers to an input document, it now holds a node-set directly, so no extension function is needed.

Try this XSLT too

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:variable name ="TestVariable">
        <video id ="0">foo1</video>
        <video id ="2">foo2</video>
        <video id ="3">foo3</video>
        <video id ="4">foo4</video>
        <video id ="5">foo5</video>
        <video id ="6">foo6</video>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="Test" select="document('')//xsl:variable[@name='TestVariable']" />

   <xsl:template match="/">
    <outofloop>
      <a2>
       <xsl:value-of select="$Test/video[@id='6']" />
      </a2>
    </outofloop>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Doesn't output expected `foo6` when I use it in .NET with `System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransform.Transform()`. It should work with any well-formed input file, right? Bug of .NET? What do you use to transform?

Comment: It might be that the "document()" function needs to be enabled in .net. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltsettings.enabledocumentfunction(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ok, it seems I have to use `XslCompiledTransform` instead of `XslTransform` to apply those settings. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >


    <xsl:variable name ="TestVariable">
        <video1 id ="0">foo1</video1>
        <video2 id ="2">foo2</video2>
        <video3 id ="3">foo3</video3>
        <video4 id ="4">foo4</video4>
        <video5 id ="5">foo5</video5>
        <video6 id ="6">foo6</video6>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <outofloop>
            <a2>
                <xsl:value-of select="$TestVariable/video6/node()" />
            </a2>
        </outofloop>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

OUTPUT-

```
<outofloop><a2>foo6</a2></outofloop>
```

Comment: If I try that, it gives me `Expression must evaluate to a node-set`.